Parallel connections sharing bandwidth vs one single connection using full bandwidth
I noticed that Filezilla opens multiple connections to FTP servers in order to upload files concurrently. However I was wondering if concurrent connections sharing bandwidth are always better than a single connection using full bandwidth. Is concurrency always faster than single connections? What are the conditions for preferring concurrency?

Think about a web browser. You want all the elements of the web page to render in parallel, not one at a time, for a more pleasing user experience. When it comes to something like file transfers, it is simply up to the application author. The author may have thought it is a more satisfying user experience to show multiple files transferring at once, rather than one at a time as you get with other applications or OSes.

@RonMaupin yeah, the browser case is different. Downloading a dynamic page takes backend time whereas downloading static files is immediate. In that case it makes sense. But when all content is ready to be sent/received, I think concurrency doesn't make sense.
